# TF Keras NAN Loss when using multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu, nvidia

**System:**

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

(2) NVIDIA GTX 1080Ti GPUs 11GB

Driver Version: 440.33.01

CUDA Version: 10.0

I am currently using Tensorflow 2.0 (Python) and the tf.keras library to train a CNN.
However, I am encountering an issue when I try to train my model by calling `model.fit()`. After 
 I begin training, the loss is normal for 1 ~ 2 steps for the first epoch. But after that, it suddenly becomes **NaN** loss. If I try to stop the kernel that is running the training script, the whole computer freezes.

This issue **only** happens when using *multiple* GPUs. The code I'm using works perfectly fine on a single GPU. I have wrapped all of my code inside the scope of a `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` using `with strategy.scope():`. I am feeding my network with data from a `tf.data.Dataset` (though this error occurs regardless of the data I'm using to train).

I then ran some tests:

1) I tried to replace the data in my dataset with random numbers from a distribution, but the loss stil went to NaN.

2) I also tried feeding the numpy arrays directly to `.fit()`, but that didn't solve the issue.

3) I tried using different optimizers (Adam, RMSprop, SGD), batch sizes (4, 8, 16, 32), and learning rates, none of which helped to solve this problem.

4) I swapped out my network for a simple Multi-layer Perceptron, but the error persisted.

This doesn't appear to be an OOM issue, since the data is relatively small and running `watch -n0.1 nvidia-smi` reveals that memory usage never exceeds 30% on either of my GPUs. There doesn't seem to be any warning or error in the console output that might hint at the issue either.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi @RodYt, Can you provide a minimum reproducible code?